# Does sin(x)/x have a singularity at 0?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, asymptotics

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, since it limits to 1, by L'hopital's rule, so it stays bounded.  But a solution that I am comparing my work to claims that 0 is a singularity for sin(x)/x.

I am using dominated convergence theorem, and want to show that $e^{-\epsilon x} \frac{sin(x)}{x}$ is bounded above by $e^{-\epsilon x}$, on $[0,\infty)$ for $\epsilon >0$.  This bound is also integrable on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: it has a removable singularity.

Comment: which means no singularity @thoth -- do you think I have to give a separate estimate, or is the upper bound I gave sufficient?  not that it's much more work, but I am just wondering if my upper bound is technically correct, in order to justify using DCT

Comment: maybe just mention that we note that sin(x)/x stays bounded near 0, @Thoth?

Comment: $\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \le 1$ for positive $x$

Comment: What's your definition of singularity? It's usually a point at which a given mathematical object is not defined, or is not differentiable, or some such thing. At $0$, this function is not defined. So that qualifies it as a singularity. But simply by definining it to be $1$, you get a continuous, differentiable function. Which is why @Thoth calls it a removable singularity.

Comment: Hi @alex.jordan, yes - now that you mention it this way, I agree, going strictly by definition.  However, is my one upper bound still good enough to justify using DCT for integration on $[0,\infty]$?  There are no issues with boundedness (and integrability of the upper bound), but as you said, the function is not defined at 0.  What do you think?  Do I need additional work?

Comment: for Lebesgue integration sets of measure zero don't matter, so just fill in that removable singularity and apply the DCT.

Comment: ok, got it - thanks so much @Thoth,

Comment: Hi @Henry, would $\large \frac {|sin(x)|}{|x|} \le 1$ for *all* x then?  thanks,

Comment: @user296605:  $\dfrac {|\sin(x)|}{|x|} \lt 1$ for *all* $x$, except $x=0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function